# How to filter Tasks to show only the active ones?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

Hello i try to query the tasks from sharepoint 2013 with javascript.

This is what i got so far:

```
 var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var userSessionManager = new SP.WorkManagement.OM.UserOrderedSessionManager(context);
    var userSession = userSessionManager.createSession();
    var userSettingsManager = new SP.WorkManagement.OM.UserSettingsManager(context);
    var locations = userSettingsManager.getAllLocations();
    var locationFilter = userSettingsManager.locationFilter
    var query = new SP.WorkManagement.OM.TaskQuery(context);
    var myTasks = userSession.readTasks(query);
    var task;
    var tasks = [];
    var overDue = [];
    var dueSoon = [];
    var anTimeDue = [];
    var dateForEvaluation = new Date();

    getMyTasks();

    function getMyTasks() {
        context.load(locations);
        context.load(myTasks);
        context.executeQueryAsync(onGetMyTasksSuccess, onGetMyTasksFail);
    }

    function onGetMyTasksSuccess() {
        console.log("Successfully retrieved tasks...");
        var taskEnumerator = myTasks.getEnumerator();
        while (taskEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            task = taskEnumerator.current;
            //console.log("Task: " + task.get_id() + " - Taskname: " + task.get_name() + " - Beschreibung: " + task.get_description() + " - dueDatum: " + task.get_dueDate() + " - Startdatum: " + task.get_startDate() + " - Persönlich: " + task.get_isPersonal() + " - Fertiggestellt: " + task.get_isCompleted());
            tasks.push({
                taskName: task.get_name(),
                description: task.get_description(),
                dueDate: task.get_dueDate(),
                startDate: task.get_startDate(),
                personally: task.get_isPersonal(),
                complete: task.get_isCompleted(),
                location: task.get_locationId()

            });
        }

        console.log(tasks);
        console.log(locations)
    }

    // This function is executed if the above call fails
    function onGetMyTasksFail(sender, args) {
        console.log('Failed to get tasks. Error:' + args.get_message());
    }
```

This code works but gives me always all Tasks back. I only need the not completed Tasks. Well i tried too look a the referenc pages but there are no code examples or anything.

So my question is how to filte the tasks to get only the not completed Tasks?

Any Advise or held would be great and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

As i discoverd the only working option for me is to us an if Statement where i query the is_completet method result.

Here is the now Working Code:

```
function onGetMyTasksSuccess() {
    console.log("Successfully retrieved tasks...");
    var taskEnumerator = myTasks.getEnumerator();
    while (taskEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        task = taskEnumerator.current;
        if (task.get_isCompleted() === false) {
            tasks.push({
                taskName: task.get_name(),
                description: task.get_description(),
                dueDate: task.get_dueDate(),
                startDate: task.get_startDate(),
                personally: task.get_isPersonal(),
                complete: task.get_isCompleted(),
                location: task.get_locationId()
            });
        }

    }

    console.log(tasks);
    countForForm(tasks);
}
```

The importend thing here is `if (task.get_isCompleted() === false)` its by no means perfect but i works good enough. Sadly the JavaScript API is not good documented for sharepoint sp.workmanagment.js.